# Why would storing a JSON object in a cookie be safer or better than a string?

Tags: javascript, json, security, cookies

I have a list of URL parameters that I obtained using JavaScript:

```
var urlParams = location.search.slice(1);
```

It was suggested to me that I store the URL parameters in a JSON object in a cookie instead of just storing the urlParams string in a cookie.

Is there any advantage (security or other) to storing the URL parameters in a JSON object vice a string if all I'm going to do is concatenate the url params with a different base url?

Comment: Doesn't matter, a string is a string regardless of the format, but JSON is generally easier to parse and stringify due to the native methods that do just that.

Comment: If you're just storing a string, there's no benefit to converting it to JSON.

Comment: JSON is a string, not an object. Cookies only store strings

Comment: JSON.parse turns a string of JSON text into an object

Comment: @adeneo—I think it's a bit of a wash. Reading and writing cookies has been around for quite a while, they're already treated pretty much just like an object, i.e. as name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object will need to be converted to a string before you persist it to a cookie.

Your code would therefore take a string, convert it to a JSON object and convert it back to a string before saving it in a cookie.

Getting your data back would require reading the string, converting to json, and back to a `urlParams` string.

Anyone who could get your `urlString` cookie, would be able to also get your `urlParamsAsStringifiedJson` cookie.  I fail to see any added security there.

Also, you might consider using `localStorage`, which has [very good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) and might be a better fit, depending on your use case.